# Infinitely differentiable functions: how to prove that $e^\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ has derivative of any order?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, induction

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) & \text{if }\vert x\vert\lt 1\\ 
0 & \text{if }\vert x\vert\geqslant 1 
\end{cases}$$

I would like to prove that $f\in C^\infty$, that is, $f\in C^k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I think that it can be done by induction on $k$. If $\vert x\vert\gt1$, the problem is trivial. On other points, the base case is the simplest and the only that I'm be able to do. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: we only really have to worry about a very small number of distinct points. Except at these points, show that every derivative of $f$ is a rational function multiplied by $f$ (using induction), and use that to verify differentiability by definition for those problematic points only.

Comment: @JonathanY. Is enough know that "every derivative of $f$ is a rational function multiplied by $f$" to verify differentiability at $-1$ and $1$? Or we need something more about the derivatives of $f$?

Comment: Further hint: exponentials and polynomials are in different growth classes.

Comment: I would do the derivative at $|x|=1$ manually (limit definition), then you can write $f'(x)$ again as a two-part function, and then do it again (manually).  What you cannot do is take the derivative for $|x|<1$ and take limits of that expression (because there are examples $x^2 \sin (1/x)$ where this gives you the wrong answer, when $f$ is not continuously differentiable)

Comment: @Pedro You should consider accepting one of the answers below if they satisfy you. I think Peter's answer is fabulous.

Comment: @anon, how does that help us? ie, why does the decay rate matter?

Comment: @TylerHilton You read the accepted answer below didn't you? It details how the derivatives pit polynomials against exponentials in the limit.

Comment: Could you show which part? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @TylerHilton "This amounts to $P(x)e^{-x}\to0$ for any polynomial $P$." There is a **substitution** implicit in this. No typo at all. Try your hand at figuring it out.

Comment: @TylerHilton I don't know if this comment will help you, but in my final solution I used $f(x)=e^{1/x}$ and proved that, for all $x<0$, $$f^{(k)}(x)=q(x)\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^{2k}},$$ where $q$ is a polynomial. So we can use the L'Hospital rule to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f^{(k)}(x)=0.$$

Comment: But your function is different in the question. I don't see how it is related

Comment: @TylerHilton In the question, we need to prove that $f(x)=e^{1/(x^2-1)}$ is $C^\infty$. We can see that $g(x)=x^2-1$ is $C^\infty$ and, by my last comment, we can show that $h(x)=e^{1/x}$ is $C^\infty$. Thus, $f(x)=(h\circ g)(x)=e^{1/(x^2-1)}$ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: Pedro, one last comment.Peter's answer deals with the function at x > 0 and 0 at x <= 0. How do they relate to your original question

Comment: @TylerHilton Notice that Peter defines a composite function and replaces $x$ by $1-x^2$. Thus, the conditions $x>0$ and $x\leq 0$  (that aren't the original conditions) implies $x^2<1$ and $x^2\geq 1$. But these inequalities are equivalent to $|x|<1$ and $|x|\geq1$ (that are the original conditions!). Does this comment answer your question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do it for $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac 1 x\right)&x>0\\ 0&x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

Note that everywhere *but* in the origin, $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Moreover, for $x>0$

$$\eqalign{
   f'\left( x \right) &= \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}f\left( x \right)  \cr 
   f''\left( x \right) &= \left( {\frac{1}{{{x^4}}} - \frac{2}{{{x^3}}}} \right)f\left( x \right)  \cr 
   f'''\left( x \right)&= \left( {\frac{1}{{{x^6}}} - \frac{6}{{{x^5}}} + \frac{6}{{{x^4}}}} \right)f\left( x \right)\cr &\&c \cr} $$

You can thus prove inductively that for $x>0$, $$f^{(k)}(x)=P_{2k}(x^{-1})f(x)$$ where $P_{2k}$ is a polynomial of degree $2k$.

As $x\to 0^+$ this amounts to looking at $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}P(x)\exp(-x)=0$$ for any polynomial $P$.

So, for any $k$, the limit as $x\to 0$ of the derivative is $0$. Now we use a slightly underrated theorem

> **Theorem** (Spivak) Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $a$. Suppose moreover that $$\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$$ exists. Then $f'(a)$ exists and $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$$

**Proof** By definition, $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$$

Consider $h>0$. For $h$ sufficiently small, $f$ will be continuous over $[a,a+h]$, and differentiable over $(a,a+h)$. Thus, by Lagrange, we can find $a<\alpha_h<a+h$ such that $$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h=f'(\alpha_h)$$

As $h\to 0^+$; $\alpha_h\to a$, and since the limit exists, $$f'(a)^+=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h=\lim_{h\to 0^+}f'(\alpha_h)=\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$$
 The case $h<0$ is analogous. $\blacktriangle$.

The above lets you conclude that indeed $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$, whence $f$ is $C^k$ for any $k$. Now, note your function is $$g(x)=f(1-x^2)$$

Comment: Is this a typo at "this amounts to looking at..." Did you mean to say $exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ in the expression?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could elaborate on how to inductively prove the formula $$f^{(k)}(x)=P_{2k}(x^{-1})f(x).$$ The base case is clear; then we simply have $f(x)=f(x)$, but how do you go about showing it holds for $k+1$?

Comment: @sunny Did you try taking the derivative of the equation for $k$ and seeing what it gives for $k+1$? Start at $k=1$, not $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking derivatives you happen to have $p(x)e^{\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}}$, where $p(x)$ is a rational polynomial function that blows up at $x = \pm 1$. What you need know is to prove the continuity of these derivatives. This, as anon suggests, turns out to be a very simple problem if you use the fact that the exponential function is way faster than every rational polynomial function. Thus, $\lim_{x \to \pm 1}p(x)e^{\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}} = 0$ $\forall p$. This means that even for $x = \pm 1$, the critical cases where the two branches need to match, every derivative of the function is continuous (in other words $\lim_{x \to \pm 1^-} f^k(x) = \lim_{x \to \pm 1^+} f^k(x)$, and this is exactly the continuity condition you were looking for).

I hope it helps :D

Comment: You will need to calculate the limit manually at $\pm 1$.